# How to get specific xpath tag value

Tags: xpath, scrapy

```
<div class="container">
<span class="price">
  <bdi> 140 </bdi>
</span>
<span class="price">
  <del>
    <bdi>90</bdi>
  </del>
  <ins>
    <bdi> 120 </bdi>
  </ins>
</span>
</div>
```

I want to scrape a site which html formatting like below. Here I dont want to bdi tag value which is under del tag and want bdi tag value which is under span class and ins tag. Is there any path to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pretty much usual `//span/ins/bdi/text()` work for you?
This is "text of `<bdi>` which parent is `<ins>` which parent is `<span>`"?
CSS variant `span>ins>bdi::text` should also work I suppose.

---

Sorry, haven't noticed that you need two values. In that case `.xpath('//bdi[not(parent::del)]/text()').extract()` will work well.

Comment: I tried your way but it will give me only value 120 but i want both 140 and 120 value under bdi tag.. This html foramtting is so clumsy to scrape..

Comment: Updated my response.